# How do I find an element using XmlDocument and then update the innertext? Using vb.net

Tags: xml, vb.net

Having trouble travesing the XML document to find a certain element so that I can 
then update the innertext.

My xml that looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FileZillaServer>
  <Groups />
  <Users>
    <User Name="jbrown">
      <Option Name="Pass">2ac9cb7dc02b3c0083eb70898e549b63</Option>
      <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
      <Option Name="8plus3">0</Option>
      <IpFilter>
        <Disallowed />
        <Allowed />
      </IpFilter>
      <Permissions>
        <Permission Dir="C:\inetpub\wwwroot">
          <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
          <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
          <Option Name="DirSubdirs">1</Option>
          <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
        </Permission>
      </Permissions>
      <SpeedLimits DlType="0" DlLimit="10" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" UlType="0" UlLimit="10" ServerUlLimitBypass="0">
        <Download />
        <Upload />
      </SpeedLimits>
    </User>
    <User Name="3-Private">
      <Option Name="Pass">test5</Option>
      <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
      <Option Name="8plus3">0</Option>
      <IPFilter>
        <Disallowed />
        <Allowed />
      </IPFilter>
      <Permissions>
        <Permission Dir="C:\Backup Spaces\3\files">
          <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
          <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
          <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
        </Permission>
      </Permissions>
      <SpeedLimits ServerUlLimitBypass="0" UlLimit="10" UlType="0" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" DlLimit="10" DlType="0">
        <Download />
        <Upload />
      </SpeedLimits>
    </User>
    <User Name="3-Public">
      <Option Name="Pass">test6</Option>
      <Option Name="ForceSsl">0</Option>
      <Option Name="8plus3">0</Option>
      <IPFilter>
        <Disallowed />
        <Allowed />
      </IPFilter>
      <Permissions>
         <Permission Dir="C:\Backup Spaces\3\files">
         <Option Name="FileRead">1</Option>
         <Option Name="DirList">1</Option>
         <Option Name="AutoCreate">0</Option>
      </Permission>
      </Permissions>
      <SpeedLimits ServerUlLimitBypass="0" UlLimit="10" UlType="0" ServerDlLimitBypass="0" DlLimit="10" DlType="0">
        <Download />
        <Upload />
      </SpeedLimits>
    </User>
  </Users>
  <Settings>
    <Item name="Serverports" type="string">21</Item>
    <Item name="Number of Threads" type="numeric">2</Item>
  <SpeedLimits>
     <Download />
     <Upload />
   </SpeedLimits>
 </Settings>
```

I'm trying to find  User Name="3-Private" and then Name="Pass" under it so I can change the password value from test5 to test10.

My console app code is:

```
    Dim xmlNode2 As XmlNode
    Dim strId As String
    Dim strElementName As String
    Dim strCurrentInnerTextValue As String
    Dim strNewValue As String
    Dim bSuccess As Boolean = False

    Dim xmlNode As XmlNode

    Dim myXmlDocument As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()

    myXmlDocument.Load("MyFileZillaforupdating.xml")

    ' Use the XmlNode object that the DocumentElement property of the XmlDocument returns to manipulate an XML node.
    xmlNode = myXmlDocument.DocumentElement

    strId = "3"

    ' Search field.
    strElementName = strId & "-Private"


    ' ----> My attempt at searching but having touble getting to the element I want.

    For Each xmlNode In xmlNode.ChildNodes
        'Find the child node.
        For Each xmlNode2 In xmlNode.ChildNodes
            If xmlNode2.Name = strElementName Then
                strCurrentInnerTextValue = xmlNode2.InnerText

                ' Going to update the password.
                strNewValue = "test10"

                Console.WriteLine("Current Innertext Value = " & strCurrentInnerTextValue & "   New Innertext value = " & strNewValue)
                ' Pause.
                Console.ReadLine()

                ' Update the XML to the new value.
                xmlNode2.InnerText = strNewValue

                bSuccess = True
            End If
        Next
    Next

    If bSuccess = True Then
        myXmlDocument.Save("MyFileZillaforupdating.xml")
        Console.WriteLine("The XML file was saved successfully.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("The entry was not found.")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) to find the password element, and then update it.

```
Dim passwordElement =
    (From u In myXmlDocument...<User>
    Where u.@Name = "3-Private"
    From o In u.<Option>
    Where o.@Name = "Pass"
    Select o).FirstOrDefault()
If passwordElement IsNot Nothing Then
    passwordElement.Value = "test10"
End If
```

This first finds the `User` element(s) with Name = "3-Private", then within those finds the `Option` element(s) with Name = "Pass", and selects the first match, if any.

You will need to use [`System.Xml.Linq.XDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) instead of `XmlDocument`, but it too has a `Load` method.

Comment: Thanks that works!!....but sure would like to know how I can do the update using the code I have.  Now given that I can use the LINQ to XML, and in this xml file, how would I code it to find and then delete the entire "3-private" user node and all its contents?

Comment: I figured out how to do the delete with LINQ to XML. Still trying to figure out how to the update with my original code.

Comment: OK, I think your issue is mainly that `xmlNode2.Name` gets the element name - i.e. `User` - not the value of the `Name` attribute.  You probably want something like `If xmlNode2.Attributes("Name").Value = strElementName Then`, but you will need to check for nulls when the attribute is not found.

Comment: Thanks so much...that gave me what I needed to finally solve this.